# Sending Packets Using TCP/IP to Use in XCode

Tags: xcode, network-programming, tcp

I'm very new to network programming, and would appreciate some help understanding what some good progress steps would be. I am designing an iOS app that requires real-time information to be delivered over a network from another machine. I know the IP address of this machine, as well as the API that the machine adheres to in terms of sending and receiving messages.

From doing some research, it seems like I need to open up a socket on one of the machine's ports, and open up another socket on my computer, and then use TCP/IP to send and receive packets between the two.

What is a good overview of the process that I need to do at this point? Which languages and environments would you suggest that would be most efficient for me to be able to get the information I need from this machine into my XCode project?

Thanks! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to look for examples of how to do "socket programming" for IOS. here's one resource:

http://www.tekritisoftware.com/sites/default/files/Socket_Programing_for_IOS.pdf

Comment: link is now a 404, any replacement known?